# Чи є в українській мові відповідник слову "communicator"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Чи є в українській мові відповідник слову "[communicator](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/communicator)" який характеризує людину, що вміє гарно доносити інформацію до інших людей?

Контекст:

> Matthew Parker (born 22 December 1980) is an Australian recreational mathematics author, YouTube personality and communicator.

Comment: Поки на думку спадає тільки *викладач.*

Answer (score 4):

[Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010р. (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=communicator&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> communicator = [kə'mju:nɪkeɪtə] перемика́ч кана́лів; комуніка́тор

СУМ-20

> [Комунікатор](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=210918&page=320) 1. Той, хто здійснює комунікацію (у 2 знач.). *За
>   умов діалогу, коли послідовно змінюються ролі учасників комунікації
>   (комунікатор перетворюється на реципієнта й навпаки), зворотний
>   зв'язок допомагає збагаченню й розвиткові інформації (з наук.-попул.
>   літ.); У міжособистісній та міжгруповій комунікації неважко визначити,
>   хто є комунікатором (з навч. літ.); Американські вчені розробили
>   загальну комунікативну модель ефективної рекламної кампанії, у якій
>   беруть участь рекламодавець (комунікатор), рекламна агенція, засоби
>   масової інформації (носій звернення) та цільова аудиторія (реципієнт)
>   (із журн.).*
>
> [Комунікація](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43411&page=320) 2. Те саме, що спілкува́ння.

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/komunikator) пропонують декілька варіантів відповідників (посилання на СУМ-11)

> спілкувальник, [мовець](http://sum.in.ua/s/movecj), [зв'язківець](http://sum.in.ua/s/zv.jazkivecj)

На сайты [Glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/communicator) пропонують переклад

> ***communicator - пропагандист***

СУМ-11

> [Пропагандист](http://sum.in.ua/s/propaghandyst)а, чол. Особа, що займається пропагандою — виступає
>   перед трудящими з бесідами, доповідями, лекціями тощо, проводить
>   політзаняття і т. ін.

Answer (score 2):

До речі, ваше речення вже переклали в українській [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80):

> Метью Паркер (народився 22 грудня 1980 року) — австралійський автор
>   рекреаційної математики, YouTube-особистість і комунікатор.

Слово "комунікатор" є і в СУМ-20, і на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0)).

Крім того, можемо подивитися варіанти [перекладу](https://translate.academic.ru/communicator/en/uk/) слова "communicator", серед тих, які можуть підійти:

> Комунікатор, фахівець з поширення інформації

Вікісловник дає синоніми до слова "комунікатор":

> (мовним чином) **мовець**, (дискусією) **дискутант**, (будучи в опозиції,
>   опонуючи) **опонент**, (хто повідомляє що-небудь) **повідомляч**, **доповідач**.

Comment: Я якраз намагаюсь перетворити цей машинний переклад у статтю. Дякую за відповідь, "фахівець з поширення інформації" найточніше відвторює зміст слова, але це звучить не так лаконічно. Думаю варто лишити як є.